# Can I navigate to a file from Visual studio to Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have project open in VS. And a file from this project is opened in VS editor. Now, I want to navigate to this file in ADO maybe to share link to team members. Is there an option to do this (maybe a context menu or something)?

Comment: To view your folders and files, choose the `Show Folder View` as mentioned here [Open a project from an Azure DevOps repo in Visual Studio](https://abouconde.com/2019/04/12/open-a-project-from-an-azure-devops-repo-in-visual-studio-2019/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a folder in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613461/display-a-folder-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Maybe I did not word the question correctly... I have project and file open in VS. And I want to navigate from VS to ADO to that particular file. Is there a context menu or something to achieve this?
P.S. I edited question now

Comment: Your question makes perfect sense to me. So far I don't see a way to do that however :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the VS extension for that called "Copy Git Link 2022" found in Visual Studio Marketplace.
If you are using Visual Studio 2022 [here's the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EtienneBAUDOUX.CopyGitLink2022). For 2019 [install this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EtienneBAUDOUX.CopyGitLink).
In addition to Azure Devops Repos it seems to support GitHub and GitLab as well.